# Get taxonomy terms by taxonomy term id

Tags: 7, views

When I'm on a taxonomy term page, I want to list all my taxonomy in that vocabulary.

So I have a taxonomy term ID in the URL. I need to lookup which vocabulary has this value, than list all the values of that vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a *Taxonomy Term* view with a *Taxonomy vocabulary: Vocabulary ID* contextual filter.

The problem here is there isn't a core-provided argument plugin for a default value. The closest thing is the *Taxonomy term ID from URL provider*, but it supplies the *Term ID*, not the *Vocab ID*. So you can:

1. Use the *PHP Code* plugin provided by Views to retrieve the term ID and return the vocab ID. (Not recommended, as it could cause various problems & won't be compatible with D8).
2. Implement a custom module with views integration via [`hook_views_plugins()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_plugins/7) and a handler that extends the [`views_plugin_argument_default`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_argument_default.inc/class/views_plugin_argument_default/7.x-3.x) class. (You can use the Views module's 
   [`views_plugin_argument_default_taxonomy_tid`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules%21taxonomy%21views_plugin_argument_default_taxonomy_tid.inc/class/views_plugin_argument_default_taxonomy_tid/7.x-3.x) provider as an example).